# Selecting multiple polygons - which polygon is top of the merge list?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge

If you select multiple polygons, and then try to merge them, ArcGIS creates the dialog box showing the selected polygons (picture below). You can then double click the one you want the others to merge into.

How does ArcGIS decide which polygon comes out top of the list?

I can't work out what criteria are used - the largest polygon, the furthest north, the most recently selected, etc?

If I knew, I could double click on the top one, rather than having to establish which one is which by clicking once to highlight the polygon.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are ordered by their position in the attribute table, top one in the merge list should be higher than second and second should be higher than third...etc.

To change which field/attribute gets listed in the merge dialog (from the default FID or ObjectID):

- In the layer Properties select>Field tab select and move up the field name which you want to show (field at 0 position is used):

[image]

This will update the merge list dialog to show in this example the "Name" field values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Additionally, do you know if/how you can change the field which is displayed within the dialog box (it appears to be based on the FID field)?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to do this.